# Что происходит с урлом?

Tags: url

Сразу прошу прощения за такую формулировку. Даже не знаю, как сформулировать по другому.
Если у моего субдомена русские буквы, к примеру "новое.my-site.com", то document.domain мне возвращает "xn--b1agweb.my-site.com". Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит с урлом, как мне правильно его генерировать (так, что бы были русские буквы) и как мне в document.domain получить адекватный результат?

Comment: Это абсолютно правильный результат и это называется punycode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать библиотеку [punycode.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/)

```js
function getDomain() {
  if (document.domain.indexOf("xn--") === 0) {
    return punycode.toUnicode(document.domain);
  }
  return document.domain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/punycode/1.4.1/punycode.min.js"></script>
```